# Корректная вставка данных в таблицу

Tags: php

Добрый день! Имеется следующий запрос:

> $result = $conn->query("Insert Into
> comments (code_blog, Name_author,
> Text_comment) 
> VALUES (".$article_id.",
> '".$_POST['posName']."',
> '".$_POST['posText']."')");

Данные $POST вставляются из формы, в которую пользователь набирает свое имя и текст.
Как можно защититься от некорректных данных и зловредных вставок кода со стороны пользователя? Кроме mysql_real_escape_string (экранирования) что можете посоветовать, друзья?

Comment: Нужно использовать PDO.

Comment: это принципиально важно? Чем mysqli плох?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проще всего - ввести ограничение на символы. Например, если и имя и пароль состоят только из букв, цифр и подчеркиваний, то сломать что-то становится крайне затруднительно.

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z_0-9]+/',$_POST['posName']);
```

Comment: я в регулярных выражениях слаб еще. А как добавить сюда еще русский алфавит в эту функцию? /[a-z,A-Z,а-я,А-я,0-9]+/ Так?

Comment: да, без запятых. Только учтите, для юникода вам потребуется u, плюс ко всему а-я не содержит ё.
Полностью для однобайтовой кодировки:

    preg_match(/[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ_0-9]+/,$_POST['posName']);

Comment: а вопрос такой еще. Пунктуация: точка, запятая, восклицательные и вопросительные знаки и тире будут тоже сюда включены? Или надо менять регулярное выражение?

Comment: подставил регулярные выражения, и что-то перестало вставлять данные... цифра 1 только в базе данных вставилась. С чем это связанно?

Comment: Надо менять.
Единица подставилась, так как preg_match - это функция для проверки. Она вернет true, если все верно и false, если кто-то пытается фигню ввести.

Для знаков препинания надо расширять регулярку. Но это плохая практика вставлять в БД знаки препинания в логине.
Если неймется, преобразуйте при помощи base64

Пароль хэшируется еще на урровне PHP;

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Тоесть preg_match - функция для корректности текста возвращающая булевой результат. А если речь идет об обычном комментарии, а не логине или пароле, там нужны и знаки препинания. Как предотвратить такую ситуацию, что пользователь введет нтмл-тег например закрывающий </div> отчего вся страница перекосится... Или зловредный js-скрипт. Как такое предотвращать?

Comment: htmlspecialchars :) 

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php